# Uploaded audio files does not play in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have developed an app which takes an .wav file as input and plays it. However it seems to be not working. On the other hand, if the audio file is placed in /www folder and path name is given, it is playing fine.

What am I doing wrong ?

**app.R**

```
library( shinydashboard )

ui = source( file.path( "ui", "ui.R" ), local = T )$value   #..... ui for ocr

server = function( input, output, session ){

  #..... Include server logic for each tab .....

  source( file.path( "server", "server.R" ), local = T )$value    #..... server logic for ocrs

}

shinyApp( ui = ui, server = server )
```

**ui.R**

```
header = dashboardHeader( title = 'Speech 2 Text' )

sidebar =  dashboardSidebar( collapsed = F,

  sidebarMenu(

  menuItem( strong( '  Speech to Text' ), tabName = 'tab1' )

  )

)

body =  dashboardBody(

  tabItems(

    #####.... tab1 ....####

    tabItem( tabName = 'tab1',

             fluidRow(

               box( title = 'Actions', status = 'success', collapsible = T, width = 12, solidHeader = T,

                    column( 6, fileInput( 'uploaded_audio', 'Choose WAV File', multiple = FALSE, accept = '.wav' ) ),

                    br(),

                    column( 3, align = 'left',

                            actionButton( 'play_audio', 'Play Audio' ),

                            tags$style( "#play_audio { vertical-align: middle; height: 30px; width: 70%; font-size: 15px;color: white;background-color:#1B618D;border-color: #374645 }" )

                    )

                  )

             )

    )

  )

)

dashboardPage( header, sidebar, body, skin = 'yellow' )
```

**server.R**

```
observeEvent( input$play_audio, {

  req( input$uploaded_audio )

  insertUI( selector = "#play_audio", where = "afterEnd",

           ui = tags$audio( src = input$uploaded_audio$datapath, type = "audio/wav", autoplay = NA, controls = NA )  
  )

})
```

Also I have printed `str( input$uploaded_audio )` to see the path where the file gets stored.

It shows output something like this :

```
data.frame':    1 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ name    : chr "newOSR_us_000_0034_8k.wav"
 $ size    : int 568810
 $ type    : chr "audio/wav"
 $ datapath: chr "C:\\Users\\MACHIN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp2zx4tW/c3d8af2a9ed3e4b8cd415aea/0.wav"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can base64-encode the file:

```
library(base64enc)

server <- function(input, output){
  observeEvent( input$play_audio, {

    req( input$uploaded_audio )

    base64 <- dataURI(file = input$uploaded_audio$datapath, mime = "audio/wav")

    insertUI( selector = "#play_audio", where = "afterEnd",

              ui = tags$audio( src = base64, type = "audio/wav", autoplay = NA, controls = NA )  
    )

  })
}
```