# How to make a Shiny App beep / play a sound after a reactive event?

Tags: r, audio, shiny

I would like a Shiny app to play a sound after a reactive event.

I already know [a solution to this at the end of an R script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365657/is-there-a-way-to-make-r-beep-play-a-sound-at-the-end-of-a-script).

On Shiny I tried:

```
library(shiny)
library(beepr)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(src = "message-handler.js")),
    actionButton("dobeep", "Play sound")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$dobeep, {
        #Beeps on local machine/server
        beepr::beep()

        #Doesn't beep on client
        insertUI(selector = "#dobeep",
                 where = "afterEnd",
                 ui = tags$audio(src = "beep.wav", type = "audio/wav", autoplay = T, controls = NA, style="display:none;")
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I put `beep.wav`in the `app.R` directory.
On local machine, I hear the `beepr::beep()`, but I don't hear the audio tag from the client.
In client/server mode, I hear nothing.
In both cases, the audio Tag doesn't seem to work.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: "In client/server mode": do you mean on a *remote* server?  if so, did you upload the wav file as well as the source code for the app?

Comment: yes, I uploaded both files on the remote server.

Comment: you could try to base64encode the file and give that as input? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926161/uploaded-audio-files-does-not-play-in-r-shiny . That works for me with your example.

Comment: OK.  There's obviously a difference between your local set up and the remote set up right?  Could it be permissions?  Does a `file.exists` tell you that the file can be found on the remote server> etc, etc...

Comment: I put the beepr test in local mode to make sure the event is triggered, but actually I don't hear the beep.wav in local mode or remote mode : see my edit

Comment: Your questions led me to the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205419/r-shiny-audio-playback). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `beep.wav` file should be in the `/www` folder, located in the same directory as the shiny app for the audio Tag to work, see [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205419/r-shiny-audio-playback).

This works :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(src = "message-handler.js")),
    actionButton("dobeep", "Play sound")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$dobeep, {
        insertUI(selector = "#dobeep",
                 where = "afterEnd",
                 # beep.wav should be in /www of the shiny app
                 ui = tags$audio(src = "beep.wav", type = "audio/wav", autoplay = T, controls = NA, style="display:none;")
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```