# R shiny not playing audio automatically

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to `autoplay` a sound which would act as an app startup sound. Below is what I am using. Now when I add `controls = TRUE`, and click on play, the audio file plays fine, but when I set `autoplay  = TRUE`, it doesn't play  on its own. How can I fix this?

```
ui = navbarPage("Project", theme = shinytheme("sandstone"),
                tags$audio(src = "Melody.mp3",type = "audio/mp3", autoplay = TRUE),
                img(src="tenor (1).gif", align = "topleft",height='90px',width='90px'),
                tabPanel("Introduction")
```

**UPDATE**

I did a find a [solution](https://olafwempe.com/how-to-enable-audio-and-video-autoplay-with-sound-in-chrome-and-other-browsers-in-2019/) using HTML. How can this be applied to Shiny?

Comment: What browser are you using? Most don't allow auto play audio because so many sites abused the attribute. This like likely a browser issue and not specific to R Shiny at all.

Comment: @MrFlick I tried in R-Studio viewer window and Chrome.

Comment: perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62369873/13513328) helps

Comment: You could autoplay files such as `audio` and `video` up to the year 2018 I think, then the policy has changed and unless the user has some sort of interaction (such a click on a page), you will not be allowed to autoplay anything, As pointed out this isn't the `shiny` issue at all, its a standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you download the `silence.mp3` file (and keep it in `www` folder) from the link you gave, you can do the following.

```
ui = navbarPage("Project", theme = shinytheme("sandstone"),
                tags$audio(src = "silence.mp3",type = "audio/mp3" ), 
                tags$audio(src = "Melody.mp3",type = "audio/mp3", autoplay = TRUE),
                img(src="mouse.png", align = "topleft",height='90px',width='90px'),
                tabPanel("Introduction") 
)

server = function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like many have said, this is a browser issue, for as long as `autoplay=TRUE` on your `tags$audio`,the user will have to turn on the sound by clicking the permission lock by the URL, then edit the site settings. Set audio permission to `allow`